# Fastest way to share big object between different Process of python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

Supose I have 3 different Process that do different logic in a forever loop. I want to run all of them in parallel and while each Process can access a `shared_object`, which is a heavy object of a class. So I tried using `multiprocessing` with a manger to archive it like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
import inspect
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
import time
import random

class SharedObject():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def show_a(self):
        print(self.a)


class ProcessManager(BaseManager):
    pass


class ProxyBase(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__')


class ManagerProxy(ProxyBase):
    pass


def register_proxy(name, cls, proxy):
    for attr in dir(cls):
        if callable(getattr(cls, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__"):
            proxy._exposed_ += (attr,)
            setattr(proxy, attr,
                    lambda s: object.__getattribute__(s, '_callmethod')(attr))
    ProcessManager.register(name, cls, proxy)


register_proxy('shared_object', SharedObject, ManagerProxy)

process_manager = ProcessManager()
process_manager.start()
shared_object = process_manager.shared_object()

def process_1():
    while True:
        print('Process 1 see {}'.format(shared_object.a))
        shared_object.a = 1
        time.sleep(1)

def process_2():
    while True:
        print('Process 2 see {}'.format(shared_object.a))
        shared_object.a = 2
        time.sleep(1)

def process_3():
    while True:
        print('Process 3 see {}'.format(shared_object.a))
        shared_object.a = 3
        if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
            shared_object.show_a()
        time.sleep(1)

first_process = multiprocessing.Process(name="First process", target=process_1)
first_process.start()

second_process = multiprocessing.Process(name="Second process", target=process_2)
second_process.start()

third_process = multiprocessing.Process(name="Third process", target=process_3)
third_process.start()

shared_object.show_a()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

It works but too slow for me since I have to pass around big numpy array. Are there any other ways to make this faster (real-time speed)? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's the problem solved by [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), but a) it looks like it's only python 3.8+ and b) the code would need to be restructured, at the very least:

- assigning the right size
- passing the name of the shared object to the processes
- and remembering to close it at the end

EDIT:

Since I couldn't get it to work with python 3.7, I decided to use it with the [shared memory primitives in 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), Array (and Value, it could be what you need). The following code runs happily:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Array


s1 = Array('i', [1])

def process_1():
    while True:
        print('Process 1 see {}'.format(s1[0]))
        s1[0] = 1
        time.sleep(1)

def process_2():
    while True:
        print('Process 2 see {}'.format(s1[0]))
        s1[0] = 2
        time.sleep(1)

def process_3():
    while True:
        print('Process 3 see {}'.format(s1[0]))
        s1[0] = 3
        if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
            print(s1[0])
        time.sleep(1)

first_process = Process(name="First process", target=process_1)
first_process.start()

second_process = Process(name="Second process", target=process_2)
second_process.start()

third_process = Process(name="Third process", target=process_3)
third_process.start()


while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Getting

```
Process 1 see 1
Process 2 see 1
Process 3 see 1
Process 1 see 3
Process 2 see 1
Process 3 see 2
3
Process 1 see 3
Process 2 see 1
Process 3 see 2
3
[...]
```

I would still pass the array to the processes, something like:

```
def process_1(shared):
    ...
```

and then

```
Process(name="First process", args=(s1), target=process_1)
```

to make it clearer what each process is working on, though.

Also, since I've not tried it with BIG objects, I am not really sure how it would fare...

Comment: Hi @Alex. Thanks for the respond. Can you give me an example how how to pass the `shared_object` to multiprocessing.shared_memory and how to access it in each process ? Also how can I calculate the right size for the shared memory area ?

Comment: at the moment, I don't have 3.8 on my machine (and being on a project, I would prefer not messing up my base python, it is a pain to fix the virtualenvs), so I would be at a loss with that: I rewrote the code in a way that works on python 3.5+, would that work for you? No allocating memory for that... (from the examples, it looks like size=a.nbytes would work, if a is a numpy array, though)

Comment: Hi @Alex. Thanks for your update. The problem is Array is much more simple than a full fat object that I need to pass arround. Let's say it have 20+ 2000x2000x3 numpy array along with other variable and stuff so multiprocessing.shared_memory might be the actual hero here. Anyways, do you have any reference for me to try `multiprocessing.shared_memory` apart from the python official docs

Comment: sadly no, it looks very new; I am planning to play with it in the next few days, but I've not seen much about it yet (I would have loved it a few years ago, but we were still using 2.7, so, well...)

Comment: Can I have some update after you get to play more with this new feature ?

Comment: as soon as I have them, yes

Comment: Thanks you @Alex